# Is it possible to count all rows with the same id with COUNT?

Tags: sql, postgresql

`PostgreSQL 9.4`.

I have the following table:

```
   id             player_id
serial PK          integer
---------------------------
   1                  1
   2                  3
  ...                ...
 123123               1
```

I need to count all rows with `player_id = 1`. Is it possible to do with the `COUNT` aggregate?

Now I do it as follows:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN player_id = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

Comment: never worked with PostgreSQL but i think it should be as in SQL Server `SELECT Count(*) FROM table WHERE player_id = 1`

Comment: `COUNT` will ignore nulls. So you could have done it as `COUNT(case when player_id  = 1 then 1 else null end)`

Comment: Read [this](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-count-function/) also ....

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If all you need is a count of the number of rows where `player_id` is 1, then you can do this:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM your_table_name
WHERE player_id = 1;
```

If you want to count the number of rows for **each** `player_id`, then you will need to use a `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT player_id, count(*)
FROM your_table_name
GROUP BY player_id;
```

Comment: This is really awesome! Thank you for providing this :)

Answer (score -1):

## For me works only something like this:

```
SELECT player_id
FROM table_name
WHERE player_id = 1 ( "and" another condition when needed)
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).