# MySQL - How can I get counts of rows in two columns, by single query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have following data:

```
| user_id | item_id |
|---------+---------|
|    3    |     2   |
|    3    |    11   |
|    4    |     1   |
|    4    |     2   |
|    4    |    55   |
|    4    |     3   |
|    5    |     9   |
```

where `item_id` is distinct in same `user_id` but it could be duplicated(see `user_id` = 3 and `user_id` = 4 have both `item_id` = 2). What I want to do is, aggregate these columns as "number of rows of `item_id` per `user_id`) which will be look like:

```
| user_id | count(`item_id`) |
|---------+------------------|
|    3    |         2        |
|    4    |         4        |
|    5    |         1        |
```

Currently I'm naïvely doing this by external logic which performs `SELECT COUNT(item_id) WHERE user_id='${user_id}'` on every `user_id`s. As you expected, this will getting worse when `user_id` is increased.

How can I write a single SQL query to achieve this? Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to count all rows with the same id with COUNT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30932283/is-it-possible-to-count-all-rows-with-the-same-id-with-count)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below with count aggregation: when you use group by with user_id, it will give you user id wise count

```
select user_id, count(item_id)
from tablename
group by user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `count` and `GROUP BY` clause to get desired result

E.g

```
SELECT user_id, count(item_id)
FROM table_name
GROUP BY user_id
```