# How to perform such queries?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am using SQLite. I create a table called MyTable, with 3 columns MyID, MyOrder, MyValue, all are INTEGER types, as follows:

```
MyID       |     MyOrder        | MyValue
1          |         3          |       2
1          |         2          |       5
2          |         1          |       8
3          |         5          |       6
```

I need to select all MyID from the table, for each MyID, also return the number of rows with that MyID.
In the above sample, the query should return:

```
        1|2
        2|1
        3|1
```

How to write this query?

Comment: The expected result doesn't match the description you gave

Comment: What have you tried? Both queries are going to involve a `GROUP BY` and an aggregating function like `MAX` or `COUNT`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL select only rows with max value on a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column) and [Is it possible to count all rows with the same id with COUNT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30932283/is-it-possible-to-count-all-rows-with-the-same-id-with-count)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT MyID, COUNT(MyID) 
FROM Table
GROUP BY MyID
```

[Reference 1](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_group_by.htm)

[Reference 2](https://www.techonthenet.com/sqlite/functions/count.php)